# I am working with xgboost library . After installing xgboost module in the environment i am still getting the error MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: python

This is the code.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

model7 = XGBClassifier(random_state=1)
model7.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred7 = model7.predict(x_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred7))
```

And this is the error. Please help me to solve this.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-47a96c9f051c> in <module>
----> 1 from xgboost import XGBClassifier
      2 
      3 model7 = XGBClassifier(random_state=1)
      4 model7.fit(x_train, y_train)
      5 y_pred7 = model7.predict(x_test)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

Comment: are working with Python 3.10? If yes, that maybe the cause as it's still a beta version and it has some issues related to some modules

Comment: no i am working with python 3.9.5, is this have same issues??

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no

Comment: then why it is  showing the error.. pls suggest something.

Comment: @R B , sorry, but I don't even know the module you're working with and I'm not expert in this type of errors. When I face them I really get nervous